# Invoking JSP inside Google App Engine application results in 404 error on production server, works on development server

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am running into a problem with invoking JSP files inside a Google App Engine application. Here is an equivalent version of the relevant configuration in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>SomeServlet.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prefix</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I try accessing `SomeServlet`in the development environment at `http://localhost:8888/prefix`this works fine, however if I try it in production at `http://someapp.appspot.com/prefix` I get HTTP error 404 (Not Found). It's `war/SomeServlet.jsp` in the file system. There is no further information in the server logs. I have also tried various access control configurations but to no avail.

What could be the reason for this failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
<jsp-file>/SomeServlet.jsp</jsp-file>
```

From the documentation:

> Note: The `<jsp-file>` must start with a forward slash (/) if the JSP is
>   in the application's root directory.

Comment: +1 for great diligence and patience. (Still somewhat strange that it worked on the development Jetty server though.)